# Java OpenESB CalculatorApp File Not Found Exception for WSDL

Tags: java, wsdl, filenotfoundexception, open-esb

I'm trying to run the example Calculator app that comes with OpenESB but I keep getting the following error.

java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8080/CalculatorApp/CalculatorWSService?wsdl

The first Calculator page works:
http://localhost:8080/CalculatorClientApp/

But when I click on "Get Result", it generates the FileNotFoundException.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved my issue using this guide: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/wsit.html

I deleted the CalculatorClientApp and CalculatorApp projects, and re-created them. Then, I right-clicked on the CalculatorApp project, selected Run, and ran it before CalculatorClientApp project. I clicked on the WSDL link on the page that opened and it worked fine. I then ran the CalculatorClientApp project and clicking on "Get Result" works now.

Running the CalculatorApp project first allows the web service to be deployed to the server. Then, by clicking the "Get Result" button, the result of the operation is retrieved from the web service and displayed in the client.